# Transfer learning with CNTK and pre-trained ONNX model fails

Tags: machine-learning, cntk, transfer-learning, onnx

I'm trying to use the ResNet-50 model from the [ONNX model zoo](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/resnet50) and load and train it in CNTK for an image classification task. The first thing that confuses me is, that the batch axis (not sure what's the official name for it, dynamic axis?) is set to 1 in this model:

[image]

Why is that? Couldn't it simply be [3x224x224]? In [this model](https://www.cntk.ai/Models/CNTK_Pretrained/ResNet18_ImageNet_CNTK.model) for example, the input looks like this:

[image]

To load the model and use my own Dense layer, I use the following code:

```py
def create_model(num_classes, input_features, freeze=False):
    base_model = load_model("restnet-50.onnx", format=ModelFormat.ONNX)
    feature_node = find_by_name(base_model, "gpu_0/data_0")
    last_node = find_by_uid(base_model, "Reshape2959")

    substitutions = {
        feature_node : placeholder(name='new_input')
    }

    cloned_layers = last_node.clone(CloneMethod.clone, substitutions)
    cloned_out = cloned_layers(input_features)
    z = Dense(num_classes, activation=softmax, name="prediction") (cloned_out)
    return z
```

For training I use (shortened):

```py
# datasets = list of classes
feature = input_variable(shape=(1, 3, 224, 224))
label = input_variable(shape=(1,3))
model = create_model(len(datasets), feature)
loss = cross_entropy_with_softmax(model, label)

# some definitions for learner, epochs, ProgressPrinters missing

for epoch in range(epochs):
    loss.train((X_current,y_current), parameter_learners=[learner], callbacks=[progress_printer])
```

X_current is a single image and y_current the corresponding class label both encoded as numpy arrays with the followings shapes

```
X_current.shape
(1, 3, 224, 224)

y_current.shape
(1, 3)
```

When I try to train the model, I get

"ValueError: ToBatchAxis7504 ToBatchAxisNode operation can only operate on tensor without minibatch data (no layout)"

What's wrong here?